# Background image doesn't cover the whole height on mobile phones

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, background

Here is the deal. I want to set a gif image as background image for the whole screen before the link opens. 
Here how it works. A user clicks on the link. With Jquery I set delay for the opening of this link. Then I remove all the elements from the page. And then I assign the gif image as a background. After that the new page is loaded. 
Everything works fine on PCs. But for some strange reason it doesn’t cover the whole height on mobile screens. Only width.
Here is my html

```
<html lang="ru" class="back_image">
```

Here is my css

```
html.back_image{
  background: url("Images/Kingdom1.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is the jquery code I use:

```
<!-- Delay for the registration link -->
<script>
function delay (URL) {
    setTimeout( function() { window.location = URL }, 4500 );
}
</script>
<!-- Remove all the elemnts on clicking registration from-->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#registration').click(function(){
      $( '#remove_all' ).remove();
   });
});
</script>
<!-- Animation for the web page after removing all the elements -->
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('#registration').click(function(){
    $('.back_image').css("background-image", "url(Images/Dragonfire2.gif)", );
   });
});
</script>
```

.back_image is the class I assigned for the html tag.

Any help?

Comment: What is `background-size` value? I think `cover` should make it work

Comment: background-size is set to cover. still doesn't work on mobile

Comment: Only the psychic people are gonna be able to answer that. For us mere mortals please show your html and css

Comment: I've just done it

Comment: I think the problem is that your html element is not covering the whole screen. try giving it a width and height equal to 100%

Comment: you may also want to try it with the body tag

Comment: I did it. Still no good. When I scroll the page on my mobile phone there's a white strip at the bottom of the page.